# Python - Excel information copying

Tags: excel, python-2.7

How do I copy the information from the 1st and 2nd columns of the 3rd sheet of an excel document.

I am using xlwt and xlrd as libraries to read and write to excel documents

This is my code:

```
import xlwt
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('input.xls')
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(2)

data = [sheet.cell_value(row, 0) for row in range(sheet.nrows)]

data = [sheet.cell_value(row, 1) for row in range(sheet.nrows)]

workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = workbook.add_sheet('test')

for index, value in enumerate(data):
    sheet.write(0, index, value)

workbook.save('Commands')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting `data`. Instead do:

```
import xlwt
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('input.xlsx')
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(2)

data = []
data.append([sheet.cell_value(row, 0) for row in range(sheet.nrows)])
data.append([sheet.cell_value(row, 1) for row in range(sheet.nrows)])

workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = workbook.add_sheet('test')

for colidx, col in enumerate(data):
    for rowidx, row in enumerate(col):
        sheet.write(rowidx, colidx, row)

workbook.save('Commands.xls')
```

Edit: To also write to txt file use:

```
with open('output.txt','wb') as fou:
    writer = csv.writer(fou)
    for row in data:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Will it open the input document and create a document called commands with the new info?

Comment: Yes it certainly looks that way. You should try it out.

Comment: Do I need these two lines, they seem to be having error's:                          for index, value in enumerate(data):
    sheet.write(0, index, value)

Comment: Wait, do I have to create a file called commands before I run this?

Comment: I updated the code in my answer. Please try that instead.

Comment: I just updated it here is the error i get: column index (256) not an int in range(256)

Comment: Ok that worked except that copied the first sheet not the third sheet. Do I just change the number in workbook.sheet_by_index(0) to 2?

Comment: Ah, yes, you can certainly do that. (In my testing I used the first sheet.)

Comment: How can I save this to a .txt file instead of an excel file?

Comment: How do I write this as columns instead of rows on the txt sheet